# How to compile a Fable VS Code plugin with Webpack?

Tags: webpack, visual-studio-code, fable-f#

```ml
module App

open Fable.Import

let activate (ctx : vscode.ExtensionContext) =
    printfn """Congratulations, your extension "fable-vscode-helloworld" is now active!"""

    vscode.commands.registerCommand("extension.helloWorld", fun _ ->
        let _ = vscode.window.showInformationMessage("Hello World!",[||])
        null
        )
    |> ctx.subscriptions.Add

let deactivate () = ()
```

The above needs the `Fable.Import.VSCode` package. I've been successful at compiling the above with `fable-splitter` thanks to instructions [here](https://blog.nojaf.com/2018/12/17/writing-a-vscode-extension-with-fable-2-1/), but I'd like to stick to a single compilation scheme so I want to get this to compile with `webpack` as well.

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: "./src/App.fsproj",
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "./public"),
        filename: "bundle.js",
    },
    devServer: {
        publicPath: "/",
        contentBase: "./public",
        port: 8080,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.fs(x|proj)?$/,
            use: "fable-loader"
        }]
    }
}
```

Here is my `webpack.config.js`. The template I am using for the project is the standard one from the Fable docs.

```
ERROR in ./src/App.fs
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vscode' in 'E:\Webdev\Fable\js-test\src'
 @ ./src/App.fs 2:0-53 6:16-24 7:4-11
 @ ./src/App.fsproj
```

When I try building it with `webpack` it complains that it cannot resolve `vscode`. What should I do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `vscode` as an external dependency so Webpack will know it should not try to bundle the extension directly in your code. VSCode will be included at runtime when needed.

You need to add this to your `webpack.config.js`.

```js
  externals: {
    "vscode": "commonjs vscode",
  }
```

Comment: Adding `libraryTarget: 'commonjs'` as one of the `output` fields is also necessary. There is a bit more info in the associated [Github issue](https://github.com/fable-compiler/fable-import/issues/94).